# Puedo utilizar tolower incluyendo unicamente la libreria string en c++?

Tags: string, headers

Hace poco, para un laboratorio de programacion en c++, nuestra profesora nos envio codigo ya implementado, donde declaraba un header hecho por ella con una funcion para quitar espacios y convertir letras mayusculas en minusculas de un string. 
 En el header la unica directiva include que puso fue #include , y en el file.cpp donde implementaba las funciones del header vi que utilizo toLower() para convertir mayusculas en minusculas, funcion que vi que esta definida en ctype.h .
Mi pregunta es, por que no necesito incluir ctype.h para que tolower funcione, a caso ctype esta ligada de alguna manera a la libreria string de c++?

Comment: OJO no escribi la unica directiva que puso... la directiva fue #include <string>

Comment: Sin ver el código todo es posible. Sube el código concreto que no entiendas y pregunta sobre él. Sino es muy posible que no consigas ninguna respuesta satisfactoria.